# HibernateException: Foreign key may not be null

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following pretty simple many-to-one relationship between Person and their parents/children (which also are instances of Person again).

**Person.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 04.05.2011 15:02:31 by Hibernate Tools 3.3.0.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="test.Person" table="PERSONS">

        <id name="id" type="long" access="field">
            <column name="PERSON_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <bag name="children" table="PERSONS" lazy="false" inverse="true" cascade="all">
            <key column="PERSON_ID" not-null="false"></key>
            <one-to-many class="test.Person" />
        </bag>

        <many-to-one name="parent" column="PARENT_ID" not-null="false" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now, the problem in my case is that I have instances of Person which do not have parents (e.g. orphans).

If I try to persist these objects, I get:

> java.sql.SQLException: null,  message
>   from server: "Column
>   'PARENT_ID' cannot be null"

If I set `not-null="true"` in the mapping file, I get:

> org.hibernate.PropertyValueException:
>   not-null property references a null or
>   transient value: test.parent

What's the magic trick here?

Comment: The first error message is coming from the server, not Hibernate. Are you sure PARENT_ID is nullable in the database table?

Comment: what if you remove `not-null="false"` from `bag` key? I have the same enviroment but with `list` instead of `bag`

Comment: @Ben Hoffstein  
I use MySQL. I let Hibernate auto-create the tables for me by setting <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

Comment: @jotapdiez That did not do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valmar, since you are getting a SQL Exception, probably your COLUMN 'PARENT_ID' have a not null constraint. Check your table DDL. What database are you using?

Comment: I use MySQL. I let Hibernate auto-create the tables for me by setting `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`.

Comment: Still, can you check the table definition in MySQL to see whether Hibernate is accurately generating a nullable column?

Comment: I dropped all tables and let Hibernate re-create them. Now the columns seems to be nullable but I get a new exception:  `java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (´mydb/PERSONS´, CONSTRAINT ´FK5A63FB1DE1B4BCAD´ FOREIGN KEY (´PERSON_ID´) REFERENCES ´PERSONS´ (´PERSON_ID´))"`

Comment: Hum... There is a FOREIGN KEY from PERSONS.PERSON_ID TO PERSONS.PERSON_ID. Drop that foreign key (and if fits your needs, create one from PERSONS.PARENT_ID TO PERSONS.PERSON_ID).

Comment: Gosh, you're right! I've been so blind (time for some coffee). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Another tip: set the one-to-many as inverse of the many-to-one relationship. Here's a post about the subject: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=940270